# Modify token used in path URL alias generation

Tags: 8, path-aliases, configuration

We would like to have the URL pattern for `Article` content type to use `article/[node:field_short_description]`. In the scenario where `field_short_description` is not populated, we would like for the URL pattern to be `article/[node:title]` as a fallback.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to use the `field_short_description` field if populated, else use the `title` field without custom code?
2. How would we do this without custom code?

We tried to use `article/[node:field_short_description]|[node:title]` but when both fields are populated, then both are added to the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution using the sample found on [How To Create A Custom Token In Drupal 8?](https://opensenselabs.com/blogs/tech/how-create-custom-token-drupal-8)

Code

```
/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function my_module_token_token_info() {
  $info = [];
  $info['types']['my_token_group'] = ['name' => t('Custom Group'), 'description' => t('Custom Group')];
  $info['tokens']['my_token_group’][‘my_token’][] = 'A token to extract desired characters from Node body to be used in meta descriptions';
  return $info;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function  my_module_token_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, \Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $replacements = [];
  if ($type == 'my_token_group') {

    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      // Find the desired token by name.
      switch ($name) {
        case ‘my_token’:
          $node = $data['node'];
          if(is_object($node) && !$node->myFieldName->isEmpty()) {
            $token_value = $node->myFieldName->value; // or something similar.
          }
          else {
            $token_value = $node->label();
          }
          $replacements[$original] = $token_value;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $replacements;
}
```